# Bootstrap 3 table responsive no scroll bar on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table responsive but on mobile devices there are no any scroll bar. Is there a way to show it on mobile device so user can understand that the table is scrollable.

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check any **table-responsive codes affected**.we should add

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

**overflow-x: hidden** means wont't work.

Comment: It is scrollable. But scroll is not visible.

Comment: Scroll bar is not visible in Android default browser and firefox. But is still possible to scroll. I need scroll bar be visible.